# Javascript hangman, game ending logic not functioning as desired

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a text based hangman game in JavaScript. I apologize if my code is redundant and over engineered. I am just learning to code. I appreciate anyone who has any input on why my game is not fully functioning.

My end-game if statements do not work at all. If I guess a letter correctly it tells me I won the game. If I guess a letter wrong it never deducts a life. I can't really understand where I am going wrong. The if statements all make sense but I think maybe I have them paired wrong?

I have a large array of random words, of different lengths

I grab a random word 'randomWord' with math.random

I initialize an empty array 'randomWordArray' and run through a for loop inserting "_" into the array for each letter of the word so I can display the word for them to guess...example: " _ _ _ _ _"

I have 4 logic statements towards in my guessLetter() function.

1. To check if the guessed letter is apart of the word, and if it is, replace the "_" at the index        of the array, with the correct letter.
2. To check if it is not apart of the word, and if not deduct a life (this never executes for some odd reason and player get unlimited lives...)
3. Check if their out of lives (never becomes true because lives never get deducted)
4. Check if the randomWordArray no longer contains any "_", meaning the word has been guessed and the game has been won and should end. (This does not work either and if the player guesses a letter correctly the game tells them they won, even if it's their first letter.)

I am open to ANY and ALL suggestions even if not related to my main issues, if you see how I am doing something redundantly or if there is a more efficient way to do something, please let me know. Thanks so much for your time.

```js
//Random array of words
const words = [
    //4 letter words
    "maze", "pate", "swig", "yawn", "belt",
    //5 letter words
    "blush", "dwarf", "fable", "haste", "jumbo", "knave", "liver", "moose", "pilot", "quill", "smile", "thief",
    //6 letter words
    "affect", "bronze", "cursor", "dancer", "fossil", "fungus", "glassy", "glitch", "kitten", "lotion","anemone", 
    //7 letter words
    "bouncing", "carpeted", "clustery", "flavored", "grapple", "lunging", "pompous",
    //8 letter words
    "abstract", "barbecue", "coffee", "clotting", "flounder", "hopping", "loudest", "pending"];

var randomWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
var randomWordArray =[];
var lives = 5;

for(i=0;i<randomWord.length;i++) {
    randomWordArray.push(" _ ");
}

function guessLetter(randomWord, randomWordArray, lives) {
    let guess = window.prompt(randomWordArray+"     Lives:"+lives);
  
  if (!guess) return; // prompt shortcut
  
  if(guess == "end") {
    window.alert("Game over");
    return;
  }
    
  //check if letter is in word
  for (i=0; i<randomWord.length; i++) {
    if (guess == randomWord[i]) {
      randomWordArray.splice(i, 1, randomWord[i]);
    }
  }
    
  //check if letter isnt in word
  if (randomWordArray.indexOf(guess) == -1) {
    lives--;
  } 
    
  //check if game should end because lives are out
  if (lives==0) {
    window.alert("Congrats the game is over!");
    return;
  }
    
  if (randomWord.indexOf("_") == -1) {
    window.alert(randomWord);
    window.alert("Congrats! You've solved the word!!");
    return;
  }
  
  if (lives > 0) {
    guessLetter(randomWord, randomWordArray,lives);
  }
}

// don't start until explicitly asked to
start.addEventListener(`click`, () => guessLetter(randomWord, randomWordArray,lives));
```

```html
<button id="start">Start</button>
```

Comment: I've turned your code into a runnable snippet, but even so: start debugging, it's almost certainly too early to ask and the first job is to form a [mcve]. For the purposes of a question, you just need a single word with two letters at most (not a giant array of words) and no random behaviour: just use that single word. Also, never have code with an infinite input loop: I've updated that so that folks can cancel out, because they will not have the patience to deal with code that runs forever and you can't break out of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that instead of

```
if (randomWord.indexOf("_") == -1) {
```

you want

```
randomWordArray.indexOf(" _ ") == -1
```

P.S.
also please do use `let i` in for loops, otherwise you create a global i variable which can go wrong and would be really annoying to debug.

P.P.S adding a snipped as asked by Michael

```js
//Random array of words
const words = [
    //4 letter words
    "maze", "pate", "swig", "yawn", "belt",
    //5 letter words
    "blush", "dwarf", "fable", "haste", "jumbo", "knave", "liver", "moose", "pilot", "quill", "smile", "thief",
    //6 letter words
    "affect", "bronze", "cursor", "dancer", "fossil", "fungus", "glassy", "glitch", "kitten", "lotion","anemone", 
    //7 letter words
    "bouncing", "carpeted", "clustery", "flavored", "grapple", "lunging", "pompous",
    //8 letter words
    "abstract", "barbecue", "coffee", "clotting", "flounder", "hopping", "loudest", "pending"];

var randomWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
var randomWordArray =[];
var lives = 5;

for(let i=0;i<randomWord.length;i++) {
    randomWordArray.push(" _ ");
}

function guessLetter(randomWord, randomWordArray, lives) {
    let guess = window.prompt(randomWordArray+"     Lives:"+lives);
  
  if (!guess) return; // prompt shortcut
  
  if(guess == "end") {
    window.alert("Game over");
    return;
  }
    
  //check if letter is in word
  for (let i=0; i<randomWord.length; i++) {
    if (guess == randomWord[i]) {
      randomWordArray.splice(i, 1, randomWord[i]);
    }
  }
    
  //check if letter isnt in word
  if (randomWordArray.indexOf(guess) == -1) {
    lives--;
  } 
    
  //check if game should end because lives are out
  if (lives==0) {
    window.alert("Congrats the game is over!");
    return;
  }
    
  if (randomWordArray.indexOf(" _ ") == -1) {
    window.alert(randomWord);
    window.alert("Congrats! You've solved the word!!");
    return;
  }
  
  if (lives > 0) {
    guessLetter(randomWord, randomWordArray,lives);
  }
}

// don't start until explicitly asked to
start.addEventListener(`click`, () => guessLetter(randomWord, randomWordArray,lives));
```

```html
<button id="start">Start</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the solution for your problem. But you can use this snippet to update your `wrong letter not deducting a life` logic

```
let lives = 2;
let myRandomWord = 'testing';

const guessWord = (wordToGuess, myWord, lives) => {

  if(wordToGuess.includes(myWord)){
     console.log('Its in the word so do something with your game logic here')
  }
  
  if(!wordToGuess.includes(myWord)){
     lives = lives - 1;
     console.log('you lost a live');
  }
  console.log('current live count ', lives)
}


guessWord(myRandomWord, 'a', lives)
```